# How can we add a template to a div in angularjs

Tags: backbone.js, angularjs, angularjs-routing

i am stuck in some concepts of backbone which i try to implement in angular js .
in backbonejs we can add a template (html page) to a particular div tag and we can render that div itself.   is possible to do same in angularjs?   adding a template to a div and render it?﻿

Comment: What's the use case of adding a template to a div and then rendering it?  You can put a template in a `script` tag and reference it from various other directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs Include Partial Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329769/angularjs-include-partial-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a template in a `script` tag and reference it by the id from `ngInclude` and `ngView`:

Docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/guilleferrer/bxdrA/1/

```
<div ng-app="">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    Content of the template.
  </script>

  <ng-include src="'/tpl.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: if we want to load an external html page(template) to a div dynamically

Comment: `ngInclude` supports that with the `src` attribute as well: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  It will allow you to include multiple "views" in a root of a template.  For Example

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2 main-menu-span">
        <div class="nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
          <ul ui-view="nav-bar" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu"></ul>
        </div><!--/.well -->
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="span10" ui-view="main">
        <div ui-view="breadcrumbs"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your module config object:

```
var tickets = {
        name: 'tickets',
        url: '/tickets',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'header.tpl.html'
            },
            'nav-bar': {
                templateUrl: 'nav-bar.html'
            },
        }
    };
    var list = {
        name: 'tickets.list',
        parent: 'tickets',
        url: '',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'list.tpl.html',
                controller: TicketQueue,
            },
        },
    };
    $stateProvider.state(tickets);
    $stateProvider.state(list);
```