# AngularJs (1.X) Include Partial Template

Tags: angularjs, templates, include, partial

I've this in my main layout file

```
<body>
    <header id="header" ng-controller="HeaderController"></header>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
```

I've a header.html partial template in my directory structure.

How to include this template in my app? I thought angular automatically includes the template after processing the controller, but it doesnt work.

The header node should be replaced with the content of this file.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? The controllers for example...

Comment: Hey, sure. But these controllers are empty atm. I've pasted bin it here: http://pastebin.com/89EzgzSH

Answer (score 98, accepted):

One way of including templates/html fragments from external files is to use the `ng-include` directive ([doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)).

```
<ng-include src="'/path/to/the/header.html'"></ng-include>
```

or

```
<div ng-include src="'/path/to/the/header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. This works! But this resolves in a another problem. I've an image tag inside in of these templates and If I include the template with ng-include, the image wont load anymore. I'm sure, that the image path is correct.

Comment: strange, haven't run into that one..it'd be safe to reference your image with the `ng-src` attribute, see if that helps

Comment: Yah, tried this already....It happens only sometimes. Maybe it has nothing to do with angular. anyways, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: The div syntax is wrong, it should be something like:

`<div ng-include="/path/to/header.html"></div>`

Comment: Just posted an edit, but I'll say it again here. Make sure to wrap string constants in single quotes like this: `"'/path/to/header.html'"`

Comment: but what if I've something like that?  <div ng-include src="'{{ part }}'"></div>

Comment: @user1315599 Then you should get rid of the single quotes, it should just be `src="{{ part }}"` - provided that `part` is of type `string`

Comment: The problem with ng-include is that it loads the partial asynchronously. So if you use it inside a custom directive that manipulates DOM, the directive's link function won't get the DOM ready.

Comment: this worked for me, thank you so much. This helped alot.

Comment: Single quotes do matter. Otherwise it's not working. I thought I did mistake and removed single quotes, and it stopped working. So you should use: `<div ng-include src="'template.html'"></div>`.

Answer (score 6):

From `Angular 2`, `ngInclude` has been [removed](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/444) and custom directives are preferred. This is the way I come up with

1. Define the main component for your app, which link to the master page

   ```
       @View({
           templateUrl:   'client/app/layout/main.html',
           directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Navigation, Footer]
       })
       @Component({selector: 'app'})
       @RouteConfig(
           routerConfig
       )
       class MainComponent {
       }
   ```

And this is the main template

```
<!---- Navigation bar ---->
<navigation></navigation>
<!----/ Navigation bar ---->

<!---- Main Part ---->
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
<!----/ Main Part ---->

<!---- Footer ---->
<footer></footer>
<!----/ Footer ---->
```

2. Define a `base.html`, which will contain the body tag and the app tag

`<body> <app>Loading ...</app> </body>`

3. Now, final step is defining the components for `Navigation` and `Footer` like the MainComponent, which point to your partial templates

Comment: With Angular2 Is there a way to use a non-visible div in your index.html as a template, for example?

Comment: I have the same question. but also need it for angular 1

Comment: We need answer about angularjs, not angular 2+.