# loading common templates into an html page with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page which contains detail sections that are common across multiple pages of my app. I am trying to reduce code redundancy and create these mini views that will be loaded with the page.

In the main detail page I have a section that I am trying to load using ng-include

```
<div ng-show="checkProducts()">
    <hr style="margin-bottom:5px!important"/>
      <p><strong><em>Products</em></strong></p>
         <div class="bs-associationPanel">
        <ng-include src="commontemplates/productView/shoes"></ng-include>
     </div>
</div>
```

I can't use routing here as this is acting like a partial view within the main detail page which is already using routes to load it and bind it to the controller.

The `src` value is a path in the APP to an html page called productView.html

I wrapped it in a script `ng-template` tag with an id

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="shoes">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>brand</th>
                    <th>color</th>
                    <th>size</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="s in detail.shoes">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{s.brand}}</td>
                    <td>{{s.color}}</td>
                    <td>{{s.size}}</td>                
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
```

I was hoping this would work but when I render the page I get no temple and looking at the element explorer I see the following

```
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

I think I am close I just don't know what I am missing. Any suggestions on how this could be accomplished or Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs Include Partial Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329769/angularjs-include-partial-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the script's with type `text/ng-template` are read by angular & angular consider it as template  then put those templates inside `$templateCache` service for faster retrieval.

`src` attribute should have template name enclosed with `'` single quotes, so that it can look up through `$templateCache` for getting the template.

```
<ng-include src="'commontemplates/productView/shoes'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: mention the symbol name as well to help the user !