# How to include template partials in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template

Angular 1.x lets you include template partials using the [ngInclude directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Angular 2+ [does not have this directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ng-include&type=). [Current suggested solutions are to create a component instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33906434/193601). I don't want to have to do this, because I doubt that every case of DRYing up a template are a case where you should make a new component. That's because I suspect that adding components for every de-dup of template code will create a separate problem of component clutter in my project and lots of unnecessary `@Component` statements around the place.

So how can you just include one template in another in Angular 2+? (Or why is it true that every case of attempted template inclusion is really a case where you should make a whole new component?)

Answer (score 0):

The truth is angular 2 does not play very well with things that manipulate the dom. That's why they deprecated ng-include with no replacement. However that said checkout this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-include which kind of worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't understand how this implementation of `ng-include` would work as a general solution because it requires all your templates to be available for individual download, and would delay render time by waiting for the response.